# Combine and display fields distributed over multiple rows in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

For a Person's Address Change Record **Table T**:

```
+----------+----------+----------+--------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| DetailID | PersonID | ChangeID | TypeID | ChangeDateTime  |     OldDetail     |    NewDetail    |
+----------+----------+----------+--------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|        1 |       10 |        1 |      7 | 7/11/2017 15:48 | 510 S Spring St   | 115 E 3rd St    |
|        2 |       10 |        2 |      7 | 7/6/2017 13:27  | 3351 Westwood     | 510 S Spring St |
|        3 |       10 |        2 |      9 | 7/6/2017 13:27  | San Diego         | Los Angeles     |
|        4 |       10 |        3 |      7 | 6/29/2017 10:38 | 661 Shatto Pl     | 3351 Westwood   |
|        5 |       10 |        3 |      9 | 6/29/2017 10:38 | Los Angeles       | San Diego       |
|        6 |       10 |        4 |      7 | 3/3/2017 13:14  | 3835 W 8th St     | 661 Shatto Pl   |
|        7 |       10 |        5 |      7 | 11/22/2016 9:23 | 123 Park          | 3835 W 8th St   |
|        8 |       10 |        5 |      9 | 11/22/2016 9:23 | San Francisco     | Los Angeles     |
|        9 |       10 |        6 |      7 | 8/3/2016 14:50  | 6650 Franklin Ave | 123 Park        |
|       10 |       10 |        6 |      9 | 8/3/2016 14:50  | Los Angeles       | San Francisco   |
+----------+----------+----------+--------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

`DetailID` is the PK. `ChangeID` represents each time just Address or Address+City change. `TypeID` represents the type of change: 7 for an Address change, 9 for a City change.

I'm trying to combine these records such that I have 1 row per change depicting both Address and City change, instead of it being spread over multiple rows. In the event that the person moves within the same city, I want the city to be copied over from the previous time a city was recorded/updated.

**Desired Output:**

```
+----------+------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
| ChangeID |       ChangeDateTime   |           OldDetail            |          NewDetail           |
+----------+------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
| 1        | 7/11/2017 15:48        | 510 S Spring St, Los Angeles   | 115 E 3rd St, Los Angeles    |
| 2        | 7/6/2017 13:27         | 3351 Westwood, San Diego       | 510 S Spring St, Los Angeles |
| 3        | 6/29/2017 10:38        | 661 Shatto Pl, Los Angeles     | 3351 Westwood, San Diego     |
| 4        | 3/3/2017 13:14         | 3835 W 8th St, Los Angeles     | 661 Shatto Pl, Los Angeles   |
| 5        | 11/22/2016 9:23        | 123 Park, San Francisco        | 3835 W 8th St, Los Angeles   |
| 6        | 8/3/2016 14:50         | 6650 Franklin Ave, Los Angeles | 123 Park, San Francisco      |
+----------+------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Read bottom to top since the sorting is by descending datetime, with the latest address being topmost. So the person first starts with living at 6650 Franklin Ave, LA and then over a series of changes finally ends up at 115 E 3rd St, LA.

I'm unable to attempt a code to give me this

Comment: I don't follow your question, partially because you just put `Address` and `City` everywhere instead of using real values which would allow someone to understand your logic.

Comment: Updated with Addresses

Comment: Are you sure you didn't switch old & new?

Comment: Yes. Added a footnote below output to explain the sequence.

Comment: Ups, sorry didn't notice the bottom-up order (why is the `changeid` ascending then?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution (as long as SQL Server doesn't support the `IGNORE NULLS` option for `LAST_VALUE`) is based on recursion. As this doesn't allow aggregation, etc., you must materialize a pivoted result first.
This can be done using *conditional aggregation*:

```
select PersonID, ChangeId, ChangeDateTime, 
   max(case when TypeID = 7 then OldDetail end) as OldAddress,
   max(case when TypeID = 9 then OldDetail end) as OldCity,
   max(case when TypeID = 7 then NewDetail end) as NewAddress,
   max(case when TypeID = 9 then NewDetail end) as NewCity
into #temp
from Table1
group by PersonID, ChangeId, ChangeDateTime
;
```

And then it's just traversing the data row by row (assuming there's a small number of address changes per person this should be reasonable fast):

```
with cte as 
 (
   select PersonID, ChangeId, ChangeDateTime, OldAddress,OldCity, NewAddress, NewCity
   from #temp as t1
   -- would be easier (ChangeId = 1) if the ChangeId was in chronological order
   where ChangeId = (select max(ChangeId) from #temp as t2 where t1.PersonID = t2.PersonID)

   union all

   select t1.PersonID, t1.ChangeId, t1.ChangeDateTime, t1.OldAddress,
     coalesce(t1.OldCity,cte.NewCity) , t1.NewAddress, 
     coalesce(t1.NewCity,cte.NewCity)
   from cte
   join #temp as t1 
     on t1.PersonID = cte.PersonID
    and t1.ChangeId = cte.ChangeId -1
 )
select PersonID, ChangeID, ChangeDateTime, 
   OldAddress + ', ' + OldCity as OldDetail, 
   NewAddress + ', ' + NewCity as NewDetail 
from cte
order by PersonID, changeid
```

See [Fiddle](http://rextester.com/MHU43486)

Comment: There should've been a TypeID inside the MAX. I tried this and it does the trick with Address and City displayed in separate fields. However, it isn't copying over the City from the previous instance in case only the Address is updated. So that field remains blank. Is there a way to include that? [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4d713/1/0)

Comment: @AS91: Yep, of course, this doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @AS91: Unfortunately SQL Server doesn't support the `IGNORE NULLS` option for `LAST_VALUE`, would be easy then. Let me think about it ...

Comment: Ty. On a side note, how does MAX (or MIN) work here on the Detail fields? If for a combination of PersonID, TypeID and ChangeID, there is only one TypeID 7 or 9, how is it selecting a MAX detail? I tried MIN and it gives me only those details which have only a TypeID 7

Comment: @AS91: Of course there's only one row per Type, but make one row out of two and the individual rows are split into different columns.

Comment: Feels like you're awfully close! `OldCity` on `ChangeID 4` should be LA and not SF since the `NewCity` on `ChangeID 5` was LA. And since there wasn't an update to the City, LA should just copy over. Similarly, `OldCity` on  `ChangeID 2` should be SD and latest City should be LA. 
I know this isn't technically a "City change" but it would help keep track of what city that address is constantly changing in until he moves out of the City. If this isn't possible, I'll go with the original pivot only solution. Thank you.

Comment: @AS91: Final try, switched to recursion :-)